# How else can I use the while-loop with the [included function] to sum only prime numbers from a given range?

Tags: python, loops, python-3.x, while-loop, primes

I'm looking for the specific number of primes that I can add together before exceeding unknown variable `n`. `k` is the number of primes.
`is_prime()` is a function that returns `True` if the argument is a prime, and `False` otherwise.

What I have attempted:

```
i = 1
total = 2
k = 0

while total <= n:
    i += 1
    if is_prime(i):
        k += 1
        total += i
```

my code begins to not work as the value of `n` gets larger. I was hoping `k` would increment only when `is_prime` returns `True`, and `total` would be a running total making sure the sum of the primes do not exceed `n`. 
How can I solve this problem using either a while-loop, for-loop, or if/elif/else, and without the use of other functions such as `sum()`?

Comment: Doesn't work how? It looks fine to me. Does it take too long? Perhaps `is_prime` is too slow, how does it work? Also you can increase `i` by 2 each time to speed things up. And you should start with `i = 3` since `total = 2` to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't seem to have a problem in it, assuming `is_prime` actually does what it's supposed to. Perhaps your `n` was just too large and looking for enough prime numbers to reach n took too long.

If any errors were raised you should have specified them, other than that, I don't really see any problem with the code.